# Sql query to convert column to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table

```
create table table1(action1 varchar(10),view1 varchar(10))

insert into table1 values('A1','VIEW'),('A1','EDIT'),('A2','VIEW'),('A3','VIEW'),('A3','EDIT')
```

I need output like this !

```
action1 VIEW    EDIT
A1  VIEW    EDIT
A2  VIEW    NULL
A3  VIEW    EDIT
```

I tried using pivot but I get error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Comment: "*I tried using pivot*" - so why don't you show us the query you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   select * from table1
    pivot
    (
    max(view1)
    for view1 in([VIEW],[EDIT])
    )as piv;
```

## <kbd>[See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14788)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use a PIVOT function for get a column from row in sql query:

```
select action1,[VIEW] as 'VIEW' ,[EDIT] as 'EDIT' from table1
    pivot
    (
    max(view1)
    for view1 in([VIEW],[EDIT])
    )as piv;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using MAX() function you can get the result

> ```
> SELECT action1,
>    MAX( CASE view1 WHEN 'View' THEN view1 ELSE '' END ) ViewCol, 
>    MAX( CASE view1 WHEN 'Edit' THEN view1 ELSE null END ) EditCol 
>    FROM table1 
>    GROUP BY action1
> ```